# Arithmetic operations on different data types in JavaScript (i.e., string vs number)

Tags: javascript, math

While digging through JavaScript's data types, I learnt that:

> Strings cannot be divided, multiplied, or subtracted, but the + operator can
>   be used on them. However, there are no such restrictions for numbers.

This is a bit self-explanatory. But, I'm still not clear with few questions like:

1. How does JavaScript implement the arithmetic operations on strings in JavaScript?
2. How is it different for different data types?
3. Or is it true, that arithmetic operations are allowed/meant only and only for numbers. For all other data types, it's just another way of representing other operations (like string/array concatenation)?

Comment: `+` on strings is concatenation. Whether or not you want to call this arithmetical is a matter of semantics. Other than that, this question is too broad.

Comment: Agreed on the point that the question could seem to be broad. I'd appreciate if you could suggest some edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are no arithmetic operators for strings, there is only the `+` operator, and that is string concatenation. `"Hello " + "World" == "Hello World"`
2. Arithmetic operations are defined for numbers and booleans, though `true` and `false` may get cast to `1` and `0`.
3. Operations with other types might either throw a SyntaxError or convert them into a string, NaN or 0. I am not too sure which when happens.